# A good approach to find security-related patches in the Linux kernel?

Tags: git, security, linux-kernel

For a research project at my University, I've been given the task of compiling a list of patches applied to the Linux kernel to fix security vulnerabilities. I'm looking to get a list of about 200.

I've checked out the master branch of the Linux kernel and am walking the git logs, but I'm finding it hard to know when a specific patch was introduced with the intent of fixing a security vulnerability. It's going to be hell if I have to dig into each and every commit to verify what is and isn't related to security.

I appreciate this might be broad, but is there a good source of information on what patches were introduced specifically because a vulnerability was found?

Comment: One approach is to check which patches accepted by linus have a public conversation around them.... if there isn't, well......

Answer (score 1):

I would check the stable kernels: security fixes are fixed after a release, so all security fixes should be added in a X.Y.Z (where Z>1) release: I would not consider a security fix things corrected in beta, never officially released as stable. And security fixes are ported on all supported kernels, so..

Now, for that point release, you should check the change logs. Note: according various kernel developers, a fix in kernel has potentially security implications, so many security fixes are not marked as security fixes. And sometime they release a vague fix, and only later they explain the security problem. So, try to identify security fixes from changelog description. Maybe you want to filter out fixes for architectures not in your target, or for some or all devices (so just to keep OS and sub-system fixes).

So, as a second step, check RedHat or Debian, for kernel package updates. The security announcement (for kernel updates) should mention the CVE numbers (and possibly other fixes): so you will not miss the most important fixes.

In this manner, you should have a list of security patches. There is a lot of handwork, and guesses. But with CVE numbers are probably the most serious, and possible the more exploitable ones. But nearly all other fixes (when they are not performance fixes), may have security implication. If you check some known exploits, you may see that many uses many vulnerabilities together, to get further into full capabilities).

Comment: I think you're on the right track with checking versioned releases. I went to https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions and security fixes are very clearly labeled.